# How to program an ATmega328p using a USBasp programmer?

Tags: atmega328p, usbasp

I'm learning to program an atmega328p using a usbasp programmer. I'm using this [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/gravitech_atmega328_datasheet.pdf), page 2, PDIP pin configuration. The usbasp programmer I'm using is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AX4WQ00). The armega328p chip I am using is one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JJX961X).

My program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0b00000001;

    for (;;) {
        PORTB = 0b00000001;
        _delay_ms(2000);
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which I compiled by doing:

```
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -Os -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=1000000UL main.c -o main.elf
avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data main.elf main.hex
```

Then tried to upload using:

```
avrdude -p atmega328p -c usbasp -P usb -D -U flash:w:main.hex:i
```

which results in

```
avrdude error: program enable: target does not answer (0x01)
avrdude error: initialization failed, rc=-1
        - double check the connections and try again
        - use -B to set lower the bit clock frequency, e.g. -B 125kHz
        - use -F to override this check
```

My connections are:

[image]

My breadboard looks like:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to see, but it looks like RESET and SCK are connected the wrong way.

Comment: The brown (RESET) wire is next to the blue one (with a gap between), the white wire which is SCK, is between the orange and the brown. Orange is the connected to the very last socket.

Comment: Then perhaps this is what's messing it up: Atmega328p Microcontroller with **Uno R3 Bootloader** || Isn't that bootloader preset for external 16 MHz oscillator?

Comment: Oh... if this is the case do I need an external oscillator to do anything with it? Or can I remove the bootloader and perhaps burn a different one?

Comment: The chip will use the external clock that is 0 MHz, so you have a moment 22. You need an external oscillator circuit for this. One simple solution is using an Uno with socketed 328p, so you can swap in this chip.

Comment: You mean, I swap this chip with one in an Arduino Uno, then program the right fuse of this chip while on Arduino Uno to use the internal clock? I then use it with avrdude as I'm trying to do now?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you for patiently walking me through that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From following the link you [provided](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JJX961X) it gives that the MCU comes with a bootloader for the Uno R3. That means a 16 MHz external oscillator is set and must be used in order to use the MCU.